# How to Use Flink User Configuration to display application configuration (values in application.conf)

Tags: apache-flink, config, app-config

I am curious about how to use this User Configuration option in Flink Jobmanager UI. Is there any way that my application.conf values should be exposed via flink environment and displayed in User configuration. I did not find much documentation regarding this User Configuration online.

If someone has any Idea about it, let me know.

Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This section of the UI is populated with the `GlobalJobParameters` that are set via `ExecutionConfig#setGlobalJobParameters`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    // assemble a map of values (e.g., from 'args', a file on the classpath or the jar manifest)
    Map<String, String> data = ...
    env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(new MetaData(data));

    // rest the job
    ...
    
}

// a trivial mapper around an existing map
private static class MetaData extends ExecutionConfig.GlobalJobParameters {
    private final Map<String, String> data;

    private MetaData(Map<String, String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> toMap() {
        return data;
    }
}
```